# Objective C- sqlite3 API call with invalid database connection pointer , misuse at line 162918

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Here is the code which I used in my project

```
sqlite3 *database;
    
-(BOOL)openDatabaseData
{
    
    NSArray *pathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                            NSUserDomainMask,
                                                            YES);
    
    NSString *filePath=[[pathList objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:"sample.sqlite"];
    
    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], & database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
   
    
}
-(void)executionMethod
{       if([self openDatabaseData]==TRUE)
       {
           //execute prepare statements
       }
     else
     {
      //error statements
     }
}
```

But it always shows the error log in console API call with invalid database connection pointer

Comment: Did you check the error code returned by sqlite3_open. BTW you do not show the code line that gives your error.

Comment: [logging] misuse at line 162918 of [378230ae7f]
only this is showing

Comment: it shows at the line  sqlite3_close(database);

Comment: Did you check that you do not close the database twice or close it before it is opened ?